# Angular 5 build error when attaching bootstrap css file

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I have created `angular 5` app, installed `ng-bootstrap` and trying to attach `bootstrap` css file from node_modules: `../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`. when I run `ng build` command I get followinf error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib?{"ident":"postcss","sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
at error (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:37:11)
at Function.browserslist.checkName (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:320:18)
at Function.select (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:438:37)
at /Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:207:41
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at browserslist (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/browserslist/index.js:196:13)
at Browsers.parse (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:44:14)
at new Browsers (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/browsers.js:39:28)
at loadPrefixes (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:56:18)
at plugin (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/autoprefixer/lib/autoprefixer.js:62:18)
at LazyResult.run (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:277:20)
at LazyResult.asyncTick (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:192:32)
at LazyResult.asyncTick (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
at LazyResult.asyncTick (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:204:22)
at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (/Users/***/dev/***/node_modules/postcss-loader/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:231:20)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
@ ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss 4:14-164
@ multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss ./src/styles.css
```

`node version: 8.9.1`

`typescript version: 2.6.0`

`npm version: 5.5.1`

`angular version: 5.2.0`

`bootstrap version: ^4.0.0`

`ng-bootstrap version: "^1.0.0-beta.8`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add it to the angular-cli.json config?

Comment: Yes, when I add .css file there, it causes error mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Angular CLI with Bootstrap, you need to ensure you have these versions:

- @angular/cli : 1.7.0
- Bootstrap : 4.0.0

These was a breaking change when Bootstrap 4.0.0 was released, Angular CLI team addressed it with the release of 1.7.0.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I'll try your to apply these versions